# How to re-run a squence of animation in reactjs and framer-motion

Tags: reactjs, typescript, animation, framer-motion

i have a sequence of animations that i want to run for unlimited times,
i tried this, it'works only for the first time, and the animation is not executed again

```js
async function sequence() {
    await animation.start({
      x: line_1.current?.getBoundingClientRect()?.width,
    });
    await animation.start({
      y: -Number(_line.current?.getBoundingClientRect().height) / 2,
    });
    await animation.start({
      x: Number(line_2.current?.getBoundingClientRect()?.width) * 2,
    });

    animation.start({
      transition: {
        repeatDelay: 1,
        repeat: Infinity,
        repeatType: "loop",
      },
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    sequence();
  }, []);
  
  return <motion.div className="w-3 h-3 bg-red-600" animate={animation} />
```

what I want is to run every time from the start, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`transition` should be placed at the main element rather than inside the `sequence`, since the transition attributes would be applied to every animation calls.

```
async function sequence() {
    await animation.start({
      x: line_1.current?.getBoundingClientRect()?.width,
    });
    await animation.start({
      y: -Number(_line.current?.getBoundingClientRect().height) / 2,
    });
    animation.start({
      x: Number(line_2.current?.getBoundingClientRect()?.width) * 2,
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    sequence();
  }, []);
  
  return <motion.div 
    className="w-3 h-3 bg-red-600" 
    animate={animation} 
    transition={{
        repeatDelay: 1,
        repeat: Infinity,
        repeatType: "loop",
    }}
  />
```

Comment: Including the `transition` in the `motion.div` element no matter how you sequence the animations doesn't work. If you actually tested this any got it working, can you please provide a codesandbox link of it working? Thanks!